# Geocoder : google is not defined error thrown on angular 2 with webpack

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, webpack, geocoding

I would like to get latitude and longitude for an address. I used angular2-google-maps npm package for this purpose.

```
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
declare var google: any;
export class ContactComponent 
{
  constructor(private _wrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) 
  {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getLatLon("115 23 Stockholm Sweden") ;
  }

  getLatLon(address: string) {
    console.log('Getting Address - ', address);
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                observer.next(results[0].geometry.location);
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
                observer.next({});
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    })
  }
}
```

I got an error 'google is not defined'. I know i missed some configuration.
How can i fix this? I use angular 2 with webpack.

App Module:

```
  import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

  @NgModule({
  imports: [
  AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
   apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXX'
   })],
  })
```

Comment: did u include <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&language=en-US&key=ur-key">
in your main file.

Comment: After adding this i got another error "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.". but the previous error goes off/

Comment: Add you app module code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps Api script is not being loaded at the time of calling the getLatLon() function. So I have included that in the index file which throws the following error.

> "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors."

Since google maps api script is being added by 'angular2-google-maps' while calling the map directive, it is redundant to add maps api reference in the index file. This was the reason for above error.

```
_loader.load().then(() => {
  console.log('google script loaded');
});
```

So I have added a above code in the app component constructor and remove the map script from index file fixed the issue.

This thread helped me to drive into the right direction.
https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/689

Answer (score 0):

Please make below changes

```
import {Angulartics2Module, Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics} from 'angulartics2';
import {AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader, NoOpMapsAPILoader} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
@NgModule({
        imports: [...
        Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics ])],
        providers: [..
         {provide: MapsAPILoader, useClass: NoOpMapsAPILoader}]
     });
```

Comment: Did u add http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=geocode&key=yourkey in main html page

Comment: I have added and got the "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."  I manged to fix that error. Please check my answer. Thanks for your help.